# Youngs Modulus Spring Strain

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics, physics-engine

I need to simulate steel strain. But I can not add enough strain. If I will, it exploding and damping values can not fix.

Here is my code:

```
Vector3 delta = distance_joint.FirstNode.transform.position - distance_joint.SecondNode.transform.position;
float deltalength = delta.magnitude;

// Calculate strain
float strain = (deltalength - distance_joint.Distance) / distance_joint.Distance;

// Calculate the spring force based on Young's Modulus
Vector3 force = delta.normalized * SpringK * strain;

// Calculate relative velocity
Vector3 relativeVelocity = distance_joint.SecondNode.GetVelocity() - distance_joint.FirstNode.GetVelocity();

// Damping coefficient (you can adjust this value)
float dampingCoefficient = SpringDamping;

// Calculate the damping force based on relative velocity
Vector3 dampingForce = -dampingCoefficient * relativeVelocity;

// Combine spring force and damping force
force += dampingForce;

// Apply forces to the connected nodes
distance_joint.SecondNode.AddForce(force);
distance_joint.FirstNode.AddForce(-force);
```

[Skeleton Structer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6zWO.png)

I wanna make a car skeleton.I need to simulate steel like material strain.

Comment: Is this for a game or academic / engineering purposes? Are you using spring joints?

Comment: For a game and that is joint code. I tried different algorithms but not stable yet.

Comment: Maybe reset the damping on this event: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint.OnJointBreak.html

Comment: I dont use unity joints, that's not the problem.